# External list not implementing TimeSpan field

Tags: sql-server, external-content-type, external-list

I am developing an external content type with sharepoint designer, based on a microsoft sql server table. One of the columns has the time(0) format. This is interpreted by sharepoint designer as System.TimeSpan, however if I create a list, the field is not implemented and shown. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it. The BCS (External Lists) do not have this datatype implemented. Best way is to use it as a string.
Later you can use jquery/code behind if binding to grid or any other control.

Comment: Thanks, I did that with a database view. The problem is that I have to write the data back which didn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

The data type System.TimeSpan is not supported by external lists.